# 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: A ServletContext is required to access the javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer instance' Error occurs

Tags: spring-mvc, websocket

I have this error when run junit test in spring mvc project.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'createWebSocketContainer' defined in net.ebaolife.tpa.websocket.WebSocketConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: A ServletContext is required to access the javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer instance
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:732)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A ServletContext is required to access the javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer instance
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServletServerContainerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ServletServerContainerFactoryBean.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
    ... 39 more
```

I have add below jar. And spring version is `4.3.3.RELEASE`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.28</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I found this bug in spring forum https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18939 (formerly SPR-14367).
But it only provided a workaround in spring boot, and it says it is fixed in `spring 4.3.1` .

Test class is :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath*:applicationContext*.xml" })
public class Test {
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In test class add annotation `@WebAppConfiguration`, this error is gone.